# Python return a list of lists of combinations of sequence

Tags: python-3.x, list, combinations

I have the following list in Python which comprises 0s.

```
lst = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

I’d like to create a list which comprises of lists of different combinations of 1s and 0s. Each list would be a new and unique combination and together all the possible combinations can be found in it. It would look a bit like this, if it was only with 3 items:

```
lst = [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,1], [1,1,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have done and an explanation of what is not working?

Comment: Give an example starting with [0, 0, 0] and detail every single output, otherwise no one can know what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `itertools` package, it contains the `product` function

```
from itertools import product
list(product([0,1],repeat=5))
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

edit: note that the right use of some functions from this package could give you your expected output without making for loops. As others said, it's hard to know what you want **exactly**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, but the following looks like your need.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [0,0,0,0,0]

tmp = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    l = np.copy(lst)
    l[i] = 1
    tmp.append(l.tolist())
print(tmp)

[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Three bit combinations without importing packages:

```
lst = []  
z = [lst.append(list(format(i,'03b'))) for i in range(0,2**3)]
lst  
[['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '1', '1'], ['1', '0', '0'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '1', '0'], ['1', '1', '1']]
```

For 4 bits wide, change '03b' to '04b' and range to (0,2**4)